# stop explode() expects parameter 2 to be string warning

Tags: php, get, explode

I have a form that's allow the user to select 2 or more categories.

php check url like:

```
 $categories= (!isset($_GET["categories"])?0:explode(";",$_GET["categories"]));
```

normal URL is like this

```
    site.com/cat.php?page=&categories=1;2
```

if the user change the URL to

```
    site.com/cat.php?page=&categories[1]
```

the site will show

```
      Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in...
```

so I tried to check $_GET like this

```
     is_string($_GET["category"])
```

but with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
$catString=is_string($_GET["categories"]) ? $_GET["categories"] : implode(';',$_GET["categories"]);

$categories = (!isset($_GET["categories"])?0:explode(";",$catString));
```

or I guess a better solution would be (instead of converting from array to string and back to array which is kinda silly):

```
$categories = (!isset($_GET["categories"])? "" : $_GET["categories"];

$categories = is_array($categories) ? $_GET["categories"] : explode(";",$catString));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET["categories"]))
{
    if(is_array($_GET["categories"]))
        $categories = implode(" ",$_GET["categories"]);
    else
        $categories = explode(";",$_GET["categories"]);
}
else
$categories='';
```

If it is an array use **implode** or **explode** function.